# RadGrid export to Excel format issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, export-to-excel, radgrid

In code behind, the following code will export the RadGrid data to an Excel file, but all the text has been wrapped.

```
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = True            
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()
```

[image]

If I manually select all the data and then click the "Wrap Text" button to disable wrapped text, the data seems good.

[image]

How can I disable the wrap function during export?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the event for when the Excel styles are created in your RadGrid's definition:

```
OnExcelMLExportStylesCreated="rgdReport_OnExcelMLExportStylesCreated"
```

Then in the code behind method, disable the `WrapText` attribute:

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ExcelMLExportStylesCreated(source As Object, 
    e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelBuilder.GridExportExcelMLStyleCreatedArgs)
    For Each style As Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelBuilder.StyleElement In e.Styles
        style.AlignmentElement.Attributes.Add("ss:WrapText", "0")
    Next
End Sub
```

Check out [this forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-export-data-to-excel) and [this blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10570/) for more info.